# Can $a$ be negative here?

Tags: functions, contest-math

> If $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y);\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $f(4)=16$ then find $f(3)$

I took $f(x)$ as $a^x$. Since $f(4)=16$, I got $a=2$. Thus, $f(3)=8$, which is the correct answer.

But I wonder if $a$ can be $-2$ here.

Comment: You would need to introduce complex numbers to give meaning to $(-2)^x$.

Comment: Observe that $b^{x}$ with $b<0$ is generally undefined as a real function of a real variable (in fact, it's undefined everywhere except for rational $x$ with odd denominator in lowest terms). So no, $f$ cannot take that form since it would lack most of the required domain. Moreover, $f$ isn't necessarily of the form $b^{x}$ at all. There is a potential discontinuous, pathological solution (see Cauchy's equation). Approach the problem without assuming the form of $f$.

Comment: @Jam can you post that as an answer? I'll accept it and close the thread then.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot just assume that $f(x)=a^{x}$ for some $a$.

Note that $f(x)=[f(\frac x  2)]^{2} \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Now $16=f(4)=f(2)^{2}$ and $f(2)=f(1)^{2}$. So $16=f(1)^{4}$ which gives $f(1)=(16)^{1/4}=2$. Thus, $f(2)=4$ and $f(3)=f(1)f(2)=8$.

Comment: In fact, one can show that $f(q) = 2^q$ where $q$ is a rational number (and that's the best we can do without further assumptions).

Comment: (I don't see a downvote. responding only because I was notified)

Comment: Well, someone retracted their upvote, as opposed to downvoting you.  You can click on the total number to see the split between up and down votes